# How do I print a report AND avoid the wizard window being closed?

Tags: openerp-7

This is a sample method I use to print a report from a wizard:

```python
def mymethod(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """
    """

    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
        'report_name': 'trescloud_ats_2013_report',
        'datas': {
            'model': 'sri.ats.2013',
            'res_ids': ids
        }
    }
```

How do I also avoid the wizard being closed?

Answer (score 0):

Call the report with a button with `type="action"` instead of `type="object"`. Like this you don't need to call a python method. If you need to run some python code before as well, then you should open again the wizard with the proper elements in the `return` of the function.

```xml
<button name="%(module_name.report_id)d" 
        type="action" />
```